# Get the minimum and maximum number in PHP from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a PHP code for showing data of my weather station.

I have a DB in MySQL with 5 columns.

This is my actual code:

```
<?php 

    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','dbone','root','dbdata');

 ?>
<?php 
        $sql="SELECT * from Sensor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Warsaw");
        $calpres=57;
        $caltemp=0;
        $calhumi=0;
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         ?>
         
<?php



?>

|esta=c00m000e00|data=<?php echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s"); ?>|temp=<?php echo $mostrar['value1'] - $caltemp ?>|hum=<?php echo $mostrar['value2'] ?>|pres=<?php echo $mostrar['value3'] + $calpres ?>
            <?php 
    }
     ?>
```

The actual result is:

|esta=c00m000e00|data=24-01-2021 19:42:10|temp=10.71|hum=58.20|pres=1016.12

Value1 is the column that includes the temperature. I would like to show the maximum and minimum temperature, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use SQL MAX() and MIN() functions.

Something like `SELECT MAX(value1) FROM Sensor`

Answer (score 0):

Either run 2 queries (one for min and one for max) like this:

(if your column name is temp)

```
SELECT * from Sensor ORDER BY temp DESC LIMIT 1 
SELECT * from Sensor ORDER BY temp ASC LIMIT 1
```

and the take the first and only rows from them.

A little bit cleaner way is to take all the data you need, ordered by temp, (no LIMIT at the end)

```
SELECT * from Sensor ORDER BY temp DESC
```

fetch it in an array, and get the first  tempArray[0] and the last tempArray[count(tempArray)-1] - values, they will containt min and max rows.

---

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from Sensor ORDER BY temp DESC");
$sensorArray = []

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
   $sensorArray[] = $row;
}

$max = $sensorArray[0];
$min = $sensorArray[count($sensorArray)-1];
```